# Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : invalid first argument in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, r-sf

I'm trying to run data in RDS format in the Shiny app but I keep getting this error

```
Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) :    invalid first argument
```

When I tried to run the data as CSV file, it run the Shiny app with no error but not all the components were showing on the interface because it required spatial object and transfer coordinates to lat-long which I created in the pre-prepared data (data.RDS)

The pre-prepared data (data.RDS) is an sf class where I create Geodetic CRS for the longitude and latitude I have.
I really appreciate your thoughts and suggestions regarding the error message and whether this could be related to the Shiny app or the data.

**Here's a sample of my data (dvc_read)**

```
structure(list(lat = c(40.61955, 40.61955, 40.61955), long = c(-74.02346, 
-74.02346, -74.02346), Year = c("2020", "2020", "2019"), Month = c("9", 
"1", "9"), Day = c("20", "11", "15"), Date = c("2020-09-20", 
"2020-01-11", "2019-09-15"), accident.description = c("Right lane blocked", 
"Right lane blocked", "One lane blocked"), Severity = c("3", 
"3", "3"), City = c("Brooklyn", "Brooklyn", "Brooklyn"), geometry = structure(list(
    structure(c(-74.02346, 40.61955), class = c("XY", "POINT", 
    "sfg")), structure(c(-74.02346, 40.61955), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-74.02346, 40.61955), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -74.02346, 
ymin = 40.61955, xmax = -74.02346, ymax = 40.61955), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
    input = "NAD83", wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"NAD83\",\n    DATUM[\"North American Datum 1983\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.257222101,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"latitude\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"longitude\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4269]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = 4:6, class = c("sf", 
"data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Names = c("lat", "long", 
"Year", "Month", "Day", "Date", NA, "Severity", "City"), .Label = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"))
```

**Preparing my data :**

```
dvc_wrangle <- dvc_read %>% 
  st_transform(crs = 4326) %>% 
  rename_with(tolower, everything()) %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.character), tolower)) %>%  
  mutate(
    Date = ymd(date),
    Month = case_when(
      month == 1 ~  "Jan", month == 2 ~  "Feb",
      month == 3 ~  "Mar", month == 4 ~  "Apr",
      month == 5 ~  "May", month == 6 ~  "Jun",
      month == 7 ~  "Jul", month == 8 ~  "Aug",
      month == 9 ~  "Sep", month == 10 ~ "Oct",
      month == 11 ~ "Nov", month == 12 ~ "Dec",
      TRUE ~ "Unknown"
    ),
    # clean up strings (not perfect)
    Severity = if_else(severity %in% c("5"), "unknown", severity),
    Accident.Description = if_else(accident.description == "Road closed", "Road_closed", accident.description),
    City = if_else(str_detect(city, "x"), "unknown", city), City = if_else(
      city %in% c(
        "Brooklyn", "Jamaica", "Merrick", "Roosevelt", "unclassified"
      ), "unknown", city
    ), Accident.Description = str_replace_all(accident.description, "_", " ")
  ) %>% mutate(across(c(Severity, Accident.Description, City), tools::toTitleCase))

# extract latlong cols from sf geometry and bind back to df
dvc_xy <- as.data.frame(st_coordinates(dvc_wrangle))
dvc <- bind_cols(dvc_wrangle, dvc_xy) %>% rename(longitude = X, latitude = Y)

 # Read pre-prepared data that I'll use in Shiny app
dvc <- readRDS("/data/dvc.RDS")

mo_order <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",

              "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")


 
    #######################################################################
     Load library -----------------------------------------------------------
library(dplyr)  # tidy data manipulation
library(stringr)  # string manipulation
library(janitor)  # misc tidy data manipulation
library(lubridate)  # dealing with dates and times
library(forcats)  # deal with factors
library(sf)  # geography
library(flexdashboard)  # layout of the tool (pages, frames, etc)
library(crosstalk)  # for allowing htmlwidgets to interact with shared data
library(leaflet)  # interactive maps
library(DT)  # interactive tables
library(shiny)  # interactive app framework
library(shinydashboard)  # layout
library(leaflet)  # interactive map
# UI ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**UI and server for Shiny app**

```
 ui <- dashboardPage(
      
      skin = "black",
      
      dashboardHeader(
        
        title = "Event-based Traffic Speed Prediction System",
        titleWidth = 450
      ),  # end dashboardHeader()
      
      dashboardSidebar(
        HTML("<br>"),
        box(
          title = "About",
          icon("info-circle", lib = "font-awesome"), HTML("<a href='https://www.google.come/'> System info</a>"), HTML("<br>"),
          width = 12,
          background = "blue",
          collapsible = TRUE, collapsed = TRUE
        ),
        box(
          title = "Filters",
          width = 12,
          background = "blue",
          collapsible = TRUE, collapsed = FALSE,
          selectInput(
            inputId = "input_year", 
            label = "Year",
            choices = sort(unique(dvc$Year)),
            multiple = TRUE,
            selected = sample(unique(dvc$Year), 1)
          ),
          selectInput(
        inputId = "input_month", 
        label = "Month",
        choices = unique(dvc$Month[order(match(dvc$Month, mo_order))]),
        multiple = TRUE,
        selected = sample(unique(dvc$Month[order(match(dvc$Month, mo_order))]), 3)
      ),
          selectInput(
            inputId = "input_la", 
            label = "Accident.Description",
            choices = sort(unique(dvc$Accident.Description)),
            multiple = TRUE,
            selected = sample(unique(dvc$Accident.Description), 3)
          )
        )  # end box()
      ),  # end dashboardSidebar()
      
      dashboardBody(
        
        fluidRow(
          valueBoxOutput("output_valueselection"),
          valueBoxOutput("output_valueyearla"),
          valueBoxOutput("output_valueyear"),
          tabBox(
            id = "tabset1",
            width = 12,
            tabPanel("Map", leafletOutput("output_map", height = "600px")),
            tabPanel("Table", dataTableOutput("output_table"))
          )
        )  # end fluidRow()
      )  # end dashboardBody()
      
    )  # end of ui dashboardPage()
    
    
# Server ------------------------------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Value box - year
  output$output_valueyear <- renderValueBox({
    shinydashboard::valueBox(
      value = dvc %>% st_drop_geometry() %>% filter(Year %in% input$input_year) %>% count() %>% pull(),
      subtitle = "Collisions in selected year(s)",
      icon = icon("calendar", lib = "font-awesome"),
      color = "blue",
      width = 4
    )
  })  # end of renderValueBox
  
  # Value box - year by la
  output$output_valueyearla <- renderValueBox({
    shinydashboard::valueBox(
      value = dvc %>% st_drop_geometry() %>% filter(Year %in% input$input_year, Accident.Description %in% input$input_la) %>% count() %>% pull(),
      subtitle = "Collisions in selected LA(s) and year(s)",
      icon = icon("car", lib = "font-awesome"),
      color = "blue",
      width = 4
    )
  })  # end of renderValueBox
  
  # Value box - total in your selection
  output$output_valueselection <- renderValueBox({
    shinydashboard::valueBox(
      value = dvc %>% st_drop_geometry() %>% filter(Year %in% input$input_year, Month %in% input$input_month, Accident.Description %in% input$input_la) %>% count() %>% pull(),
      subtitle = "Collisions in selection",
      icon = icon("car", lib = "font-awesome"),
      color = "blue",
      width = 4
    )
  })  # end of renderValueBox
  
  # Interactive map with Leaflet
  output$output_map <- renderLeaflet({
    dvc %>%
      filter(
        Year %in% input$input_year,
        Month %in% input$input_month,
        Accident.Description %in% input$input_la
      ) %>% 
      leaflet() %>% 
      addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap) %>% 
      addAwesomeMarkers(
        icon = awesomeIcons(
          icon = "exclamation-circle",
          iconColor = "#FFFFFF",
          library = "fa",
          markerColor = "darkblue"
        ),
        popup = ~paste0(
          "<style>
            td, th {
              text-align: left;
              padding: 3px;
            }
            </style>",
          "<table>",
          "<tr>","<td>", "Date", "</td>", "<td>", date, "</td>", "<tr>",
          "<tr>","<td>", "LA", "</td>", "<td>", accident.description, "</td>", "<tr>",
          "<tr>","<td>", "City", "</td>", "<td>", city, "</td>", "<tr>",
          "<tr>","<td>", "Species", "</td>", "<td>", severity, "</td>", "<tr>",
          "</table>"
        )
      )
  })  # end of renderLeaflet
  
  # Interactive table with DT
  output$output_table <- renderDataTable({
    dvc %>% 
      st_drop_geometry() %>%
      filter(
        Year %in% input$input_year,
        Month %in% input$input_month,
        Accident.Description %in% input$input_la
      ) %>%
      select(
       Date = Date,
        Year = Year,
        Month = Month,
        `Accident.Description` = Accident.Description,
       City = City,
        `Severity` = Severity
      ) %>%
      datatable(
        filter = "top",
        extensions = c("Scroller", "Buttons"),  # scroll instead of paginate
        rownames = FALSE,  # remove row names
        style = "bootstrap",  # style
        width = "100%",  # full width
        height = "800px",
        options = list(
          deferRender = TRUE,
          # scroll
          scrollY = 300,
          scroller = TRUE,
          # button
          autoWidth = TRUE,  # column width consistent when making selections
          dom = "Blrtip",
          buttons =
            list(
              list(
                extend = "collection",
                buttons = c("csv", "excel"),  # download extension options
                text = "Download"  # text to display
              )
            )
        )  # end of options = list()
      )  # end of datatable() 
  })  # end of renderDataTable()
  
}  # end of server function


# Run ---------------------------------------------------------------------


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Update II**

I'm providing a fully reproducible example of the RDS file of my data.

```
structure(list(lat = c(40.61955, 40.61955, 40.61955), long = c(-74.02346, 
-74.02346, -74.02346), year = c("2020", "2020", "2019"), month = c("9", 
"1", "9"), day = c("20", "11", "15"), date = c("2020-09-20", 
"2020-01-11", "2019-09-15"), accident.description = c("right lane blocked", 
"right lane blocked", "one lane blocked"), severity = c("3", 
"3", "3"), city = c("brooklyn", "brooklyn", "brooklyn"), Date = structure(c(18525, 
18272, 18154), class = "Date"), Month = c("Sep", "Jan", "Sep"
), Severity = c("3", "3", "3"), Accident.Description = c("Right Lane Blocked", 
"Right Lane Blocked", "One Lane Blocked"), City = c("Brooklyn", 
"Brooklyn", "Brooklyn"), longitude = c(-74.02346, -74.02346, 
-74.02346), latitude = c(40.61955, 40.61955, 40.61955), geometry = structure(list(
    structure(c(-74.02346, 40.61955), class = c("XY", "POINT", 
    "sfg")), structure(c(-74.02346, 40.61955), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-74.02346, 40.61955), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -74.02346, 
ymin = 40.61955, xmax = -74.02346, ymax = 40.61955), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
    input = "EPSG:4326", wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Horizontal component of 3D system.\"],\n        AREA[\"World.\"],\n        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = c("4", 
"5", "6"), class = c("sf", "data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(lat = NA_integer_, 
long = NA_integer_, year = NA_integer_, month = NA_integer_, 
day = NA_integer_, date = NA_integer_, accident.description = NA_integer_, 
severity = NA_integer_, city = NA_integer_, Date = NA_integer_, 
Month = NA_integer_, Severity = NA_integer_, Accident.Description = NA_integer_, 
City = NA_integer_, longitude = NA_integer_, latitude = NA_integer_
), .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"))
```

Comment: The problem appears to reside in your UI section where you sample selections for the widgets. Did you test what gets returned for each of those (e.g. `sample(unique(dvc$Month), 3)`)?

Comment: In fact, fro the Month variable, shouldn't it be: `sample(unique(dvc$Month[order(match(dvc$Month, mo_order))]), 3)`?

Comment: Thank you for your notes! I modified the sample selections for the Month as you mentioned and updated the code but I'm still having the same error message. any other recommendations please

Comment: So when when you run the `sample(...)` lines on their own, you don't get any error?

Comment: No, I don't get any errors when I run sample (...) by itself. But when I use the same data in its original CSV format, I'm able to run Shiny and navigate through the interface, but when I run the prepared data. as an RDS object, I face this error message. I've been trying to solve this error for three days without any luck

Comment: It's difficult to help further without a fully reproducible example. If you are able to run the `sample()` function lines off the data frame that is saved as an RDS file, than I'm at a loss to explain why it occurs.

Comment: Maybe in the `server.R` file, add something like `observe(print(unique(dvc$Month[order(match(dvc$Month, mo_order))])))` to see if anything odd is returned in the console.

Comment: I just updated the question and provided a reproducible example of the RDS file.. not sure if this can help but I'm very frustrated about how to fix this issue in my Shiny app, and I really appreciate your help

Comment: For `sample(unique(dvc$Month[order(match(dvc$Month, mo_order))]), 3)` is there a reason why you're picking 3? Why not 1? You'd get an error if there are less than 3 unique elements to sample from.

Comment: 3 is just what the default selections will be,, so I'll have 3 months shown on the interface. changing them into 1 or other numbers doesn't really help.. thank you, Phill! will keep looking for a solution.